# Latex in Inkscape is not working anymore after update

Tags: latex, inkscape

I have been using the render-latex option in Inkscape for many years happily. Now, after some updates I get an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "eqtexsvg.py", line 160, in 
>       e.affect()
>     File "/usr/share/inkscape/extensions/inkex.py", line 283, in affect
>       self.effect()
>     File "eqtexsvg.py", line 154, in effect
>       svg_open(self, svg_file)
>     File "eqtexsvg.py", line 81, in svg_open
>       doc = inkex.etree.parse(filename)
>     File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3426, in lxml.etree.parse
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1839, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1865, in lxml.etree._parseDocumentFromURL
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1769, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFile
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1162, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFile
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 600, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 710, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
>     File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 637, in lxml.etree.*raiseParseError
>   IOError: Error reading file '/tmp/inkscape-MvWHN*/eq.svg': failed to load external entity "/tmp/inkscape-MvWHN_/eq.svg"

I updated Ghostscript to version 9.26 and I have Inkscape version 0.92.4. 
In addition, I have installed `pdf2svg' as suggested in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1034894/render-latex-is-not-working-in-inkscape-after-installing-to-18-04/1035923).

Does anybody have a clue how to solve this issue?

Comment: How did you installed Inkscape? Please add output of `which inkscape` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert the command `which inkscape' gives me: /usr/bin/inkscape

Comment: Could you please edit your question to make it more reproducible? I have already installed Inkscape. What else should I install? How can I get render-latex option? Does simple clicking on *Extensions* → *Render* → *LaTeX* correct method? What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: I don't recall how to get the render-latex option, I think it just came directly with the installation on Ubuntu... and indeed one simply clicks Extensions --> Render --> Latex

Comment: Going to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/1759483 and clicking "Does this bug affect you? --> Yes" might give it higher priority.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** - it is [bug 1759483](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/1759483).

---

I have followed [LaTeX guide from Inkscape wiki](http://wiki.inkscape.org/wiki/index.php/LaTeX), so I installed

```
sudo apt-get install texlive pstoedit
```

then I launched Inkspace, selected *Extensions* → *Render* → *LaTeX* and I can't get it working on Ubuntu 18.10, 19.04 and 19.10.

So it is a known [bug 1759483](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/inkscape/+bug/1759483).

Installation of latest version of Inkscape from official PPA, Snap or FlatHub does not help either.

**But it works on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and 18.04 LTS.**

Answer (score 0):

To solve this bug I I built this [docker container](https://github.com/ludwigprager/inkscape-latex)
There's an example included, too.